# Mover todas las letras mayúsculas al principio de la palabra

Tags: javascript, string

Realiza una función que reciba como parámetro un string y mueva todas las letras mayúsculas al principio de la palabra.

> **Ejemplo:** soyHENRY **->** HENRYsoy

```
function capToFront(s) {    
    var mayuscula = '';    var minuscula = '';
    for (i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
    if(s === s.toUpperCase()){
      mayuscula = mayuscula + s.toUpperCase;
      return (mayuscula.push());
    }
    else if(s === s.toLowerCase())
      minuscula = minuscula + s.toLowerCase;
      return (minuscula.push());   }   return (mayuscula + minuscula) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Codigo no probado!*
Según entiendo, necesitas interar entre cada letra de tu entrada e ir comprobando si está en mayuscula, mi sujerencia serían estos métodos

```
function comprobarMayuscula(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase(); //Devuelve true o false dependiendo del caso
}
function comprobarLetra(str) {
    let palabraMayuscula; let palabraMinuscula;
    for(let i = 0; i < str.lenght; i++){
      let letra = str.charAt(i); //Interactua entre cada letra de tu palabra
      let mayuscula = comprobarMayuscula(letra); //Comprobamos si es mayuscula
      if(mayuscula){
        //Si entra, significa que es mayuscula
        palabraMayuscula+= letra //Concatenamos la letra mayuscula
      }else{
        palabraMinuscula += letra //Concatenamos la letra minuscula
      }
  }
  //Al terminar el ciclo, concatenamos ambos resultados y lo retornamos
  return palabraMayuscula + palabraMinuscula;
}
```

Espero almenos ayudarte con la lógica si no funciona el código

Comment: excelente logica, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hice así:

```js
function capToFront(s) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i in s) {
    if (s[i] === s[i].toUpperCase()) {
      arr.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  for (let i in s) {
    if (s[i] !== s[i].toUpperCase()) {
      arr.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
}
console.log(capToFront('soyHENRY'))
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pues algunos detalles:
Poner return dentro de cada if, por tanto el bucle no se ejecutaría cuando se cumple un if
Usas s.toUpperCase() completo pero estas comparando letras, debes usar s[i]
Al consturir la cadena de mayúsuclas y minúsculas pones s.toUpperCase, sin los paréntesis.
Si s[i] es igual s s[i].toUpperCase(), pon directamente s[i]
El segudno if sobra, aunque eso no es un error.

```js
console.log(capToFront("soyHENRY"));

function capToFront(s) {
  var mayuscula = '';
  var minuscula = '';
  for (i = 0; i<s.length; i++){ 
     if(s[i] === s[i].toUpperCase()){ 
          mayuscula = mayuscula + s[i]; 
       }
   else {
          minuscula = minuscula + s[i];
        } 
   }       
  return (mayuscula + minuscula) 
}
```

Comment: excelente, muchas gracias por la explicación!

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice así

```
function capToFront(s) { 
  var strRet = "";
  for(let i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
    if (s[i] === s[i].toUpperCase()){
      strRet = strRet + s[i];
    }
  }
  for(let i = 0; i<s.length; i++){
    if (s[i] === s[i].toLowerCase()){
      strRet = strRet + s[i];
    }
  }
  return strRet;
}

console.log(capToFront("HoLaAtOdOs"))
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

```
function capToFront(s) {
  //Realiza una función que reciba como parámetro un string y mueva todas las letras mayúsculas
  //al principio de la palabra.
  //Ejemplo: soyHENRY -> HENRYsoy
  //Escribe tu código aquí
  let Str = "";//mayusculas
  let str = "";//minusculas
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {//recorre el string
    if (s[i] === s[i].toUpperCase()) {//si el indice es equivalente a una mayuscula
      Str += s[i];//mayuscula concatena con string en dicho indice
    }
    else {
      str += s[i];//de lo contrario minuscula concatena con string en dicho indice
    }
  }
  return Str + " " + str;//retorna "MAYUSCULAS"+"espacio"+"minusculas"
}
```